# Most efficient way of deleting elements from an np array using a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy` array as of right now that looks something like:

```
A =  [  [5, 8, 6, 2], 
        [5, 8, 6, 2], 
        [...], ...       ]
```

Let's say I have another 1D `numpy` array, that looks something like array `B`, but has at values that correspond to each of the lists inside `A`.

```
B = [0.4, 0.6, 0.3, ...]
```

Now I want to delete any list within the list that has a corresponding value within `B` that is greater than 0.5 (this could be represented by a variable named `thresh`). The resulting array should look like (since the second list had a greater value):

```
C =  [  [5, 8, 6, 2], 
        [...], ...       ]
```

I am looking for a good `numpy` based/ pythonic way of achieving this. I am aware of np.delete, but do not understand how to use it here with a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about condition `Boolean` slice

```
A[B<0.5]
Out[197]: 
array([[5, 8, 6, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Cool solution! But is there a `numpy` way of doing this?

Comment: I tried `A[B<thresh`] and I got `boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0;`

Comment: @SharanDuggirala is A and B have same len ? , print len(A) and len(B)